# What is meant by "Linq evaluates query one method at a time"?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I've read somewhere that "*Linq evaluates query one method at a time*". What exactly is it meant by that? Perhaps that operators are called in the order specified – for example, in the following code `Select` is called before `Where`:

```
var results = someCollection.Select(...).Where(...);
```

while here `Where` is called before `Select`:

```
var results = someCollection.Where(...).Select(...);
```

Is this what is meant by "*evaluating query one method at a time*"?

Thank you

Comment: I think perhaps the comment was framed in reference to the differences between LINQ creating Enumerable wrappers for the nested method calls for in memory queries vs. queries that are executed as an expression tree (for an IQueryProvider)....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a citation that tells us exactly where you read that, we can only guess at the meaning.

I would interpret that phrase to mean that multiple LINQ methods act as a pipeline, i.e. each piece of data flows through before the next one does.

For example:

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var results = numbers.Select(number => number * 2).Where(number => number > 3);
```

With eager evaluation, the execution would look like this:

```
1, 2, 3 -> Select -> 2, 4, 6 -> Where -> 4, 6
```

However, with deferred evaluation, each result is calculated when it is needed. This turns the execution of the methods "vertical" instead of "horizontal", executing all methods for each data item, then starting again with the next data item:

```
1 -> Select -> 2 -> Where -> nothing
2 -> Select -> 4 -> Where -> 4
3 -> Select -> 6 -> Where -> 6
```

Of course, this is not true for methods which operate on the whole set, such as `Distinct` and `OrderBy`. All of the data items must "pool" there until execution can continue. For the most part, though, LINQ methods only ask for items from the source when they themselves are asked for another item.